# ¿Por qué me aparecen errores de sintaxis en vs code usando las extensiones de PHP?

Tags: php, vscode

Uso PHP 8.
Uso el editor de texto Visual Studio Code, Tengo las extensiones PHP DEBUG, PHP Intelephense y PHP InteliSense y en el código PHP, me marca errores que en verdad no lo son, a que se debe esto? En los errores dice:

')' expected php
'{' expected php
'}' expected php

unexpected 'public' php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, las que mencioné en la descripción PHP DEBUG, PHP Intelephense y PHP InteliSense, ademas PHP Server

Comment: **Parece** ser debido a que el plugin aún [**no tiene soporte total**](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1525) para todas las características agregadas en PHP 8 como el *constructor property promotion*, entonces si de momento dicho plugin no lo puede resolver solo deberás ignorarlo

Comment: Cual es la versión por default que estás utilizando? en la terminal escribe `php -v`. Si la versión 8 es predeterminada, no debería mostrar esas lineas como error.

Comment: PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021 23:43:39) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 ). ¿Cómo la pongo predeterminada?

Comment: si es lo primero que te salio, solo corriendo el comando en terminal, eso quiere decir que está como predeterminado. Intenta desactivando las extensiones. Yo no tengo dichas extensiones y el código me lo marca como correcto.